# How to add scrollbars to a TComponent?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

I am using a 3rd party control which is descended from TComponent and I want it to have scrollbars, preferably autoscrollbars.

Can I get them from TComponent?

Failing that, can I place a TPanel on my mainform & the component on that and get scrollbars? I intend to have the component (and Panel, or whatever) be alClient so that they autoresize when my component resizes, but I woudl also like them to have (auto) scrollbars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood what you're intended to do, do this:

- add a TScrollBox on the form
- add **visual** components on the TScrollBox component
- don't worry about scroll bars, because they will be shown automatically when needed(when a component is out of the visible area)
- have fun!

Comment: +1 Thanks, Dorin. I am sure this is the way to go. It is not currently working, but I will look into it further & hopefully get to the bottom of it

Comment: Hmm, perhaps not working because my 'control' is a form which I am placing on another form (along with some other controls) ?

Comment: I don't think so... in one of my projects I've created a custom "database search" on multiple tables, etc. and they way the user creates conditions is that on the search form I have a scrollbox and on the scrollbox I add comboboxes, lookupcomboboxes, etc.(dynamically) I can't see why forms would react in any way different. Don't align the secondary form to "alClient" add it to Left = 0, Top = 0 so that when the parent form shrinks the child form will keep it's size, however the scrollbars will appear if it's necessary in order to show the entire content of the child form.

Comment: Please ignore last comment - it is not  a TForm

Comment: no worries, same apply to other controls, add it to it's normal size to the scrollbox, and if it's bigger in width, height or both than the scrollbox(which should be aligned to client), the scrollbox will take care of your needs, furthermore it's much cleaner than doing something "dirty" which might(might not...) get you into problems later on... just my two cents.

Answer (score 3):

For visual controls you usually descend from TControl or (better) TWinControl. TWinControl is a wrapper around Windows controls (widgets), and Windows can provide scrollbars for contents. You might want to look at TScrollbox source code as a guide or a replacement for your TPanel idea.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to answer. Unfortunately,, it is a 3rd party control, so I just have to live with what I have (hence my thought of adding it as a child something which I can control and and making it alCLient.

Comment: @Leonix can't you get the source of this component?

Comment: @Leonix even third-party control is usually descended from TWinControl or TForm (which is a descendant of TWinControl). However from your comments I see that you have formulated your needs incorrectly. You don't need to add scrollbars to control, but want to fit larger control to limited viewing space. So just put the control to TScrollBox.